# Abrindo site externo no android studio dentro de um item de lista

Tags: android, android-fragment

Bom preciso abrir um link externo por exemplo:

```
https:www.google.com.br
```

Porém ele deve ficar dentro de um litem de lista de menu (menu lateral). Para abertura dos fragments utilizo a posição do item, existem 7 posições as citadas abaixo.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentListaRestaurantes_())
                .commit();
        break;

    case 1:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(BACKSTACK)
                .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentFavoritos_())
                .commit();
        break;

    case 2:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(BACKSTACK)
                .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentMeusPedidos_())
                .commit();
        break;

    case 3:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(BACKSTACK)
                .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentMeusDados_()).commit();
        break;
    case 4:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(BACKSTACK)
                .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentIndique()).commit();
            break;
    case 5:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(BACKSTACK)
                    .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentIndique()).commit();
            break;
    case 6:
        sair();
        break;
    }
}
```

A posição dele é a 5.

A minha duvida é a seguinte, preciso mandar ele para um fragment qualquer e la redirecionar ou tenho como definir o click diretamente deste case, chamando uma função que faça este trabalho ?

E como devo programar isto ?

Comment: Não entendi a questão. No `case` pode colocar o código que quiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer mandá-lo pra um navegador externo a aplicação?

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
case 5:
   String url = "http://www.google.com.br";
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(i);
break;
```

Comment: Brother funcionou perfeitamente, justamente o que eu queria